# Show hidden div when scrolled halfway through viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

*EDIT* Hopefully this is more clear. :)

Right now, as you scroll down, you'll notice that the pink colored div only appears when it touches the top of the viewport. How can I make it appear when it touches half way through the viewport?

https://jsfiddle.net/1p751fz5/

```js
// constants
var BTN_CLS = 'owl-thumb-item',
  BTN_ANIMATION_MILLIS = 200,
  DIV_ANIMATION_MILLIS = 1000;

// document ready handler
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  // display buttons from first 'div'
  showBtns('one', BTN_CLS);
  
  // window scroll handler
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.hidden').each(function(i, v) {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top) {
       // show 'div' when scrolling
       showDiv($(this), onCompleteDivAnimation($(this)));
      }
    });
  });

});

/**
 * Used to show an animated 'div' and perform some actions.
 * @param {Function} completeCallback Action performed after animation.
 * @param {Object} div Target element.
 */
function showDiv(div, completeCallback) {
  // check if 'div' is currently animated and avoid animation queue
  if (!div.is(':animated')) {
    div.animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, {
      complete: completeCallback,
      duration: DIV_ANIMATION_MILLIS
    });
  }
};

/**
 * Used to perform actions after completing a 'div' animation.
 */
function onCompleteDivAnimation(div) {
 showBtns(div.prop('id'), BTN_CLS);
};

/**
 * Used to show button(s) from a 'div' element.
 * @param {String} divId Target element Id.
 * @param {String} btnCls Button(s) CSS class.
 */
function showBtns(divId, btnCls) {
  var btnGroup = getBtnGroup(divId, btnCls);

  animateBtn(btnGroup);
};

/**
 * Used for creating a group of button(s) from a 'div' element.
 * @param {String} divId Target element Id.
 * @param {String} btnCls Button(s) CSS class.
 * @returns {Array} btnGroup
 */
function getBtnGroup(divId, btnCls) {
  var domBtns = $('#' + divId + ' .' + btnCls),
    btnGroup = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < (domBtns || []).length; ++i) {
    btnGroup.push(domBtns[i]);
  }

  return btnGroup;
};

/**
 * Used to animate a button group that normally comes from a 'div' element.
 */
function animateBtn(btnGroup) {
 btnGroup = btnGroup || [];

  $(btnGroup.shift()).fadeIn(BTN_ANIMATION_MILLIS, function() {
    if (btnGroup.length > 0) {
      animateBtn(btnGroup);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: `imagePos ` is only set once on page load and is using `this` which is window

Comment: @charlietfl So I need to have it be called multiple times? o.o

Comment: yes...be aware that scroll event fires many many times a second ... should use some debouncing for better performance

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with jquery. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s13gjnwt/16/

On scroll, get the window height, the amount the user has scrolled, and the top position of the hidden div. (I set an offset of half the window height so the div won't appear until after it's in 50% in the viewport)

JS

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  var scrollAmount = $(window).scrollTop();
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var halfHeight = $(window).height() / 2;
  var topOfHiddenDiv = $('.hidden-div').offset().top;
  if(((scrollAmount + windowHeight) - halfHeight) >= topOfHiddenDiv && !$('.hidden-div').hasClass('show')) {
    $('.hidden-div').addClass('show');
  }
});

.content {
  padding-top: 1000px;
}
.hidden-div {
  background: lightblue;
  color: @white;
  padding: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}
.hidden-div.show {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

NOTE: Make sure to scroll down in the fiddle

Comment: The use of scrollTop here is key, especially since it was missing in the original code.

Comment: @JoshSanger Hi, I updated OP to hopefully be more clear. I tried to incorporate your code into mine but I didn't get it correct. Does the `$(window).on('scroll', function(){`  replace `$(document).ready(function() {`?

Comment: Nope, $(document).ready() is still required to ensure the DOM loads first. The $(window).on('scroll') function would be placed inside that.

Comment: The way you have the code in the fiddle makes It wait until the element is at the top of the screen to show it. If you want to show it at 50% you need to get the window height and use that as the comparison https://jsfiddle.net/1p751fz5/3/